# PHP: PDOStatement simple MySQL Select doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following PHP code doing a very simple select into a table.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE fbid = :fbid");
$statement->bindParam(":fbid",$uid, PDO::PARAM_STR,45);
$out = $statement->execute();
print_r($out) // 1;
//$out = $statement->execute(array(':fbid' => $uid)); // also doesn't work
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

`$out` is true (success) yet `$row` is null.

EDIT:

`$statement->debugDumpParams();`

Outputs

`SQL: [40] SELECT * FROM account WHERE fbid = :fbid Params: 1 Key: Name: [5] :fbid paramno=-1 name=[5] ":fbid" is_param=1 param_type=2`

If I modify the code as follows:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE fbid = $uid");
$out = $statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

`$row` contains the record I'm expecting.

I'm at a loss. I'm using the PDO::prepare(), bindParams() etc to protect against SQL Injection (maybe I'm mistaken on that).

EDIT:
In my example, $uid is a numerical string (ie a string containing only numbers). In the database, the column type is VARCHAR(45)

EDIT:

If I change the database type from VARCHAR(45) to BIGINT, both queries work. If I change the type in the database type back to VARCHAR(45) again, it works. So what gives?

Please halp.

Comment: can you post the results of `print_r($out);`

Comment: ok, for shits and giggles try without the `, PDO::PARAM_STR,45` in bindParam

Comment: so it would look like `$statement->bindParam(":fbid",$uid);`

Comment: @Jayrox: $row is still null. I'm so confused. This *should* work. In fact, I have a similar select statement that does work (albeit in a different table)

Comment: also, Facebook suggests that UIDs be stored as `Bigint(20)` in mysql

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=31736

Comment: Right, but PHP doesn't have native support for Bigints on 32bit hardware. Rather than use HiLo, I figured storing them as varchar would be okay.

Also +1 for figuring out facebook id :)

Comment: lol, just re-read your code and noticed you didnt mention facebook at all... i develop a facebook app in php with PDO using fbid ;)

Comment: I think you may not have a proper PDO library installed. May not support actual prepared statments. I just ran this query on my server and it returned the expected results.

Comment: Also, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: i have edited my answer with example code for my database and actual results.

Comment: @Charles: PHP Version 5.2.11

@Jayrox: hrm. This is the default installation that comes with a dreamhost account. I can open a service ticket and see whats up. I've used a prepared statements for insert with success, also with a select into a different table.

Comment: dreamhost is using 32bit servers?

Comment: I'm not sure. They might be running a 64-bit VM host, but the actual VM is 32 bit. PHP_INT_MAX is 2^31-1

Comment: I dunno, I cant seem to find a reason you wouldnt be able to use it here, but can use it in other tables.

Comment: What happens if you set the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute to true before the prepare?

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the values are being inserted into the table. If I change the column type in the table to bigint, it works. If I switch it back to varchar(45) it still works, but if I write a new row, the new row isn't found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there may be an issue with your PDO installation.

```
$uid = 552192373; // my facebook uid for testing
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE facebook_uid = :fbid");
$statement->bindParam(":fbid",$uid, PDO::PARAM_STR,45);
$out = $statement->execute();
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [facebook_name] => Jason Boehm
    [facebook_uid] => 552192373
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your fbid value. it should be always string if its integer value is greater than 2^32 (unsigned), simply cast by (string)$uid is not work, and sprintf("%.0f",...) will only works when integer value less than 2^52, because on 32-bit OS when a number is greater than 2^31(32 unsigned) PHP will assume it is double type and default precise is only 14 decimal but fbid is 20.

You have to keep fbid in string contains only [0-9] in PHP, doesn't matter it is stored as BIGINT or VARCHAR in MySQL, MySQL accepts only string sql statement and always returns result in string format.

```
$mi = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "xxx", "test");
$uid = "12379739851403943597";   // Works
//$uid = 12379739851403943597;   // never Works
//$uid = (string) 12379739851403943597;   // get "1.2379739851404E+19" wrong string !
//$suid = sprintf("%.0f", $uid);          // get "12379739851403943936" lost precise

$stmt = $mi->prepare("select * from bitest where id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $uid);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $name);

$stmt->store_result();
print "numrow: " . $stmt->num_rows . " - \n";
$stmt->fetch();
print "$id - $name \n";
$stmt->free_result();

$stmt->close();


$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', 'xxx');
$sql = "select * from bitest where id = ?";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$sth->execute();
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while... try passing a hash to [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) instead:

`$statement->execute(array( 'fbid' => $uid ));`

Comment: Have you tried using positional params instead of named?  `"SELECT * FROM account WHERE fbid = ?"` and `execute(array($uid))`?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the extra parameter,

```
$statement->bindParam (":fbid", $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**(edit)**
Are you 100% positive there is no extra whitespace surrounding the UID?  Test with [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and pass by value:

```
$statement->bindValue (":fbid", trim($uid), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try PDO::PARAM_INT

Aside from that, keep in mind bindParam() takes the variable as a reference. Maybe your demo code doesn't show you changing the value of that variable before execute() is called. See bindValue() if needed.

Comment: changing it to int, doesn't return a result. Also, I do an "echo" of the $uid value, and it's what I expect. I've also tried bindValue(), and that doesn't work either.